# intellisense in Gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have intellisense working in a Gruntfile?

Since 'grunt' is not a global variable but a parameter in the Gruntfile VSCode will assume that it is just an unknown function parameter 'any'.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {...}
```

When I add the type to the parameter, intellisense is working just fine, but grunt will not, since it is JS and not TS.

```
module.exports = function(grunt: IGrunt) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `gruntfile.ts` and use TypeScript with intellisense. The compiled version (`gruntfile.js`) will then be used by GruntJs.

Answer (score 5):

Steps for the uninitiated...

## Setup Typings

**Install Typings for Grunt**

```
npm install --save @types/grunt
```

**Locate Typings File**

Ensure your IDE knows the location of this typings file:

```
./node_modules/@types/grunt/index.d.ts
```

## Using Auto-completion

This is possible in .ts or .js, whichever you prefer...  (I use typescript, because the compiler does a lot of type-safety checking)

**Auto-completion in Typescript**

Rename your existing gruntfile.js to gruntfile.ts.

Add IGrunt type to enable auto-completion:

```
module.exports = function (grunt: IGrunt) {
    // auto-complete works for grunt-dot now
    ...
}
```

Lastly, remember to compile your gruntfile.ts so that it produces a new gruntfile.js.

**Auto-completion in Javascript**

If you prefer to avoid typescript....

Use [jsdoc](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch29.html) to enable auto-completion in javascript:

```
/**
* 
* @param {IGrunt} grunt
*/
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // auto-complete works for grunt-dot now
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with JavaScript, this will run just as well as your JavaScript, but with intellisense just good as that with `grunt: IGrunt`:

```js
/**
 * @param {IGrunt} grunt
 */
module.exports = function (grunt) {...}
```

(Why yes, there *is* already [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418276/294313) that suggests doing this, but I wanted to make it clear that this could be **all** you need to do.)

In Visual Studio Code, this won't work if you have `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` set to `true` (or the feature hits some kind of snag) and don't have `@types/grunt` in your `package.json`, but if any of that was the case, `grunt: IGrunt` wouldn't appear to work either.